# Verify method with Delegate parameter in Moq

Tags: moq, delegates, parameters, verify

Using Moq for generation of Stubs and Mocks in my unit tests, I have a case where I want to Verify that a method that takes a Delegate parameter is called. I don't care about the particular Delegate parameter supplied I just want to make sure that the method is in fact called. The method looks like this:

```
public interface IInvokerProxy{
    void Invoke(Delegate method);
    ...
}
```

In my tests I would like to do something like this:

```
invokerProxyMock.Verify( proxy => proxy.Invoke( It.IsAny<Delegate>));
```

Currently it gives me an error *Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'*. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're missing the parentheses on `It.IsAny<Delegate>()`.

Comment: Great. You get to know these things when you make the same mistake yourself a few times :D